# CSS class before and after the element

Tags: css

I have a simple question

What is the difference between these two statements?

Ex:

```
.job-des li{
//you styles here
}
```

AND

```
li.job-des{
//you styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.job-des li{
//you styles here
}
```

In this chunk of code

`li` can lies anywhere in a elemenet whose class is `job-des` 
like

```
<div class="job-des">
    <ul>
        <li>This is selected as per the conditions  </li>
        <li>This is selected as per the conditions  </li>
        <li>and this one too   </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

in this code it will select all `li's` which is in the specific class

AND in this

```
li.job-des{
//you styles here
}
```

only those `li's` will be stylized whose class is given `.job-des`

```
<div class="any class">
        <ul>
            <li>  i am not selected</li>
            <li class="job-des">i am selected as per the conditions  </li>
            <li> and this one too is not selected  </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

**First** 
`.job-des li{` this will apply to the `LI` which is child of `.job-des` class.

**Example**

```
<div class="job-des"><li></li></div>
```

**Second** `li.job-des {` this will apply to `LI` having job-des class.

**Example**

```
<li class="job-des"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is `<li>` elements contained in any element that has the class `.job-des`, while the second is any `<li>` elements that themselves have the class .job-des

For instance, the first would hit this:

```
<div class='job-des'>
    <ul>
        <li>It hits me</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

while the second would hit this:

```
<ul>
    <li class='job-des'>It hits me</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .job-des li{
 //This style will apply in li of the element have class .jobs-des
 }
```

AND

```
 li.job-des{
 //This style will apply on li which have class .job-des
 }
```